# How can I write a Python code to return a certain combination of letters and numbers?

Tags: python

I have to pull certain metadata from a data set. I'm only interested in a certain field whose key is the letter 'p' followed by an integer and then another letter 's'.

For example, my first dataset has the following fields that I need to extract:

```
P7s
P8s
P9s
p10s
p12s
```

Is there anyway to write a code to return those items?

This is my code right now where I specify what in the data set will match with the required metadata form in the application where I'm loading the files.

The issue is with 'Markers analysed' where I would like to specify if 'Markers analysed'= p # s then return that value.

```
metadata_crosswalk={
    'Date of Analysis': 'date',
    'Creator':'export user name',
    'Instrument':'cyt',
**    'Markers analysed': ,**
    'Number of Samples':'tot'
}

for coscine_key,fcs_key in metadata_crosswalk.items():
    print("looking at metadata key (coscine)", coscine_key)
    print("looking to store fcs metadata key", fcs_key, "| value:", fcs_metadata[fcs_key])
    metadata[coscine_key]=fcs_metadata[fcs_key]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to extract the fields.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'p\d+s')

for coscine_key,fcs_key in metadata_crosswalk.items():
    print("looking at metadata key (coscine)", coscine_key)
    if fcs_key is not None:
        print("looking to store fcs metadata key", fcs_key, "| value:", fcs_metadata[fcs_key])
        metadata[coscine_key]=fcs_metadata[fcs_key]
    elif coscine_key == 'Markers analysed':
        matching_fields = [field for field in fcs_metadata.keys() if pattern.match(field)]
        print("matching fields:", matching_fields)
        metadata[coscine_key] = matching_fields
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. The part that I am struggling with now is that the matching keys are showing but not the values. I now need to load the values into Coscine. Any advice on that part?

Comment: something like this, `for coscine_key, fcs_key in metadata_crosswalk.items():
    print("looking at metadata key (coscine)", coscine_key)
    if fcs_key in fcs_metadata:
        value = fcs_metadata[fcs_key]
        print("looking to store fcs metadata key", fcs_key, "| value:", value)
        metadata[coscine_key] = value
    else:
        print("fcs metadata key", fcs_key, "not found")`